# Conformal mapping of a stripe to upper half of a plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I need to find conformal mapping $W$ which maps half-infinite stripe $Z$, bounded by $2\mathbb{i}$ and $5\mathbb{i}$, to upper half plane.

In other words this is what I **have**:

[image]

And this is what I **want**

[image]

I know that $W_1=e^z$ will give me a ring region with radius $e^2$ and $e^5$.

Then my idea was to combine the ring region and the inverse region together to get the full plane: $W_2=(W_1+\frac{1}{W_1})$.

Then I wanted to take only $W_3=Im(W_2)>0$ to get the upper half plane. But I failed to get the analytical expression for $W_3$.

Could you please help me with that? Or maybe I chose the wrong path from the begining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. $e^z$ maps the strip $0<Im(z)<\pi$, to the upper half-plane.
2. Now, translate and shrink the given region to $0<Im(z)<\pi$, $0\leq Re(z)$.
3. A certain polynomial map will give you the final result.

Comment: Ok, I can translate it and srink but I wont get an infinite strip which I need for $e^z$ mapping. How can I get strip which is not bounded by $x=0$, but lies all over the $x$ axes.

Comment: Hint: How would you map the right quadrant of the upper-half plane to the entire upper-half plane?

Comment: Do u mean this mapping $W=z^2$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: actually, I found more elegant way to do this. As my final result I got that $W=cosh(-\frac{\pi}{3}z-i)$